# How can I use Private IP publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, tomcat8

I have created one Amazon Lightsail Windows instance. Amazon is providing one public and private IP. I have installed Tomcat 9 into that instance. Tomcat is running with that private IP . But private IP is not accessible from outside of that virtual machine. How will I use this private IP publicly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO as you cannot access a private IP from outside VPC.

Private IP as the name implies is private and is only accessible within the VPC. If you want to access the tomcat over the internet then you need to use the public IP.

Comment: yes. i understood your point. but when i am trying to access tomcat by public ip [ 13.234.119.148:8080] it is providing one error [ 504 gateway time out or couldn't connect to the requested server host] . can you tell me how could i solve it?

Comment: Have u tried changing the connector setting to listen on  0.0.0.0 in server.xml

Comment: See also: [Understanding public network ports and firewall settings in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it from outside your cloud, you can't - it will exist in one of the three subnet ranges reserved for internal networks (10.x.x.x, 172.16-31.x.x or 192.168.x.x).

From inside your cloud, what you need to do is find out what ports Tomcat is listening on and create a Security Group that grants access to these ports - then other instances launched within the same VPC and Subnet will be able to connect.